# Laravel single query different output

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have query like this

```
$query = MyModel::query()->where('status', 1);
```

and I want to get a different output

```
$result1 = $query->where('type', 1)->count();
$result2 = $query->where('type', 2)->count();
$result3 = $query->where('type', 3)->count();
```

result for `$result2` and `$result3` is wrong. So I try to get the raw queries from this

```
$result1 = $query->where('type', 1)->toSql();
$result2 = $query->where('type', 2)->toSql();
$result3 = $query->where('type', 3)->toSql();
```

the raw query shows

```
select * from `my_table` where `status` = ? and `type` = ?
select * from `my_table` where `status` = ? and `type` = ? and `type` = ?
select * from `my_table` where `status` = ? and `type` = ? and `type` = ? and type = ?
```

why Laravel added the `where` condition to `$result2` and `$result3`?

Comment: Probably because you're building on `$query` multiple times and it's stacking the where clauses

Comment: add ``clone`` keyword before every query your query relations are being stacked on top of each query hence ``and`` is showing on query which will result in incorrect results